# Unable to render the multi-select and single-select based on the condition?

Tags: apex, visualforce, rendered

[image: Expecting only checkboxes for multiselect type questions and radio buttons for singleselect type questions, but here both checkboxes and radiobuttons are displaying for multiselect type questions - how can these be rendered]

Am unable to render the multiselect and singleselect in the vf page, suggest me to fix this.

code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="OnlineExAnswer" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:form id="frm" >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Questionare">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:repeat value="{!onWrprList }" var="qustwrpr">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!qustwrpr.que.Question_Des__c }" rendered="{!qustwrpr.que.Question_Type__c='Multi-Select'}"/> 
                    <!--  <apex:outputField value="{!qustwrpr.que.Answer_Option__c}"/> -->
                    <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!qustwrpr.ansList}"> 
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!qustwrpr.anss}"/> 
                    </apex:selectCheckboxes>
                   <!-- <apex:outputField value="{!qustwrpr.que.Question_Des__c }" rendered="{!qustwrpr.que.Question_Type__c='Single-Select'}"/>
                    <apex:selectRadio value="{!qustwrpr.ansList}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!qustwrpr.anss}"/> 
                    </apex:selectRadio> -->

                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>     
</apex:page>
```

Apex:

```
public class OnlineExAnswer{
    public List<Question__c> questionList {get; set;}
    public List<OnlineWrapper> onWrprList {get; set;}
    public List <String> ansList {get; set;}
    private Account acc;
    public OnlineExAnswer(ApexPages.StandardController Controller){

        onWrprList=new List<OnlineWrapper>();
        acc= (Account) controller.getrecord();
        System.debug('::::::'+acc);
        Account acc1=[Select Id,MasterSetAcc__c from Account where Id=:acc.Id Limit 1]; // with this query we can get fields of Account.
        questionList= [Select Question_Des__c,Answer_Option__c, Question_Type__c  from Question__c where MasterSet1__c=:acc1.MasterSetAcc__c];
        for(Question__c que : questionList){

            OnlineWrapper owrpr = new OnlineWrapper();
            owrpr.que = que;
            if(que.Question_Type__c == 'Multi-Select'){
                system.debug('::::: answerOption String'+que.Answer_Option__c);
                List<string> ansList=que.Answer_Option__c.split(';');
                system.debug('########' + ansList);
                for(String ans:ansList){
                    owrpr.anss.add(new selectOption(ans,ans)); 
                }
                system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@'+ owrpr.anss);


                owrpr.isCheckBox= true;   
            }
            else if(que.Question_Type__c == 'Single-Select'){
                List<string> ansList=que.Answer_Option__c.split(';');
                for(String ans:ansList){
                    owrpr.anss.add(new selectOption(ans,ans)); 
                }
                system.debug('^^^^^^^^^^^^'+ owrpr.anss);
                owrpr.isRadiobutton= true;   
            }
            else{
                owrpr.isText= true;  
            }
            onWrprList.add(owrpr); 
        }

        system.debug('$$$$$$$$'+ questionList.size());
        system.debug('%%%%%%%%'+ onWrprList.size());

    }


    public class OnlineWrapper{
        public List<String> ansList {get; set;}
        public List<SelectOption> anss{get;set;}
        //  public List<String> selectedOptions{get;set;}
        public Question__c que {get; set;}
        public Boolean isCheckBox {get;set;}
        public Boolean isRadioButton {get;set;}
        //public String text{get;set;}
        public Boolean isText{get;set;}
        public OnlineWrapper(){
            ansList=new List<String>(); 
            anss=new List<SelectOption>();
            this.isCheckBox=false;
            isRadioButton=false;
            isText=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what the expected behavior is and what you observe.

Comment: @Adrian Larson : I just wanted to display only checkboxes for multiselect and radiobuttons for singleselect. Unable to render, attached the screenshot.

Comment: @Sweety4sfdc please, add description to the screenshot. Is it expected behavior? Or it's what you would like to see?

Comment: Expecting only checkboxes for multiselect type questions and radio buttons for singleselect type questions, but here both checkboxes and radiobuttons are displaying for multiselect type questions - how can these be rendered

Comment: so all the above questions in the screenshot are multi select questions?

Comment: @SarathGarimella : Yes....!!

Comment: Is your page code correct, I am unable to see where you are setting radio buttons. Looks like its commented out. Please update your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is you are not rendering properly based on Question Type. Wrap the question type options inside `outputPanel` and display those conditionally.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!onWrprList }" var="qustwrpr">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!qustwrpr.que.Question_Type__c='Multi-Select'}">
        <apex:outputField value="{!qustwrpr.que.Question_Des__c }"/> 
        <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!qustwrpr.ansList}"> 
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!qustwrpr.anss}"/> 
        </apex:selectCheckboxes>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!qustwrpr.que.Question_Type__c='Single-Select'}">
       <apex:outputField value="{!qustwrpr.que.Question_Des__c }"/>
        <apex:selectRadio value="{!qustwrpr.ansList}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!qustwrpr.anss}"/> 
        </apex:selectRadio>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```

Which will finally display like this:

[image: Questions]